# Why is another else if statment running javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, execution

So I am working on a loan calculator in JavaScript. So I keep running into this problem to where when a user enters a number for above 400 but below 500 it will not run that if statement but instead it will run the other else if statement where if a number is above 500 and below 640. The following code I am talking about is down below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
else if (500 < getCredit < 640){
        alert("This is it");
        score += 6
        console.log("The score is " + score);
    }

    else if (400 < getCredit < 500) {
        score += 0 // The else if statement above is executed and not this  one whenever conditions are met
    }
```

Below is the rest of code
**Js code**

```
    function myFunction() {

    score = 0;

    var getCredit = parseInt(document.getElementById("credit").value);
    if(getCredit > 640){
        score += 12
        console.log("The score is " + score);// This is working the right way
    }

    else if (500 < getCredit < 640){
        alert("I learned something at Mathnasium");
        score += 6
        console.log("The score is " + score);
    }

    else if (400 < getCredit < 500) {
        score += 0
    }
}
```

Comment: `(500 < getCredit < 640)` isn't what you think it is

Comment: @JaromandaX would you elaborate on that statement please.

Comment: They’re saying go look up some basic JavaScript stuff—you’re making up syntax.

Comment: think of your statement as `((500 < getCredit) < 640)`  because `<` are evaluated left-to-right... now, `(500 < getCredit)` is either true (1) or false (0) ... the 0,1 are what true/false are coerced to for the next part of the statement... and both 1 and 0 are < 640 - so that `else if` is always true

Comment: (500 < getCredit < 640) is the issue your having here. That syntax doesn't amount to what your trying to do. I think you should do a else if (getCredit > 500 && getCredit < 640), you'll get what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (getCredit >= 640) {
    // credit is 640 or more
}
else if (getCredit >= 500) {
    // credit is 500 or more, and less than 640 because of the "if (getCredit >= 640)" above
}
else if (getCredit >= 400) {
    // credit is 400 or more, and less than 500
}
```

---

`else if (500 < getCredit < 640){` is evaluated from left to right as

```
else if ( (500 < getCredit) < 640) {
```

which is evaluated to `(true < 640)` or `(false < 640)`, **but** both of them result in true:

```js
console.log(500 < 1 < 640)   // true   (false < 640)

console.log(true  < 640)     // true

console.log(false < 640)     // true

console.log(true  == 1)      // true 

console.log(false == 0)      // true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {

    score = 0;

    var getCredit = parseInt(document.getElementById("credit").value);
    if(getCredit > 640){
        score += 12
        console.log("The score is " + score);// This is working the right way
    }

    else if (getCredit > 500 && getCredit <= 640){
        alert("I learned something at Mathnasium");
        score += 6
        console.log("The score is " + score);
    }

    else if (getCredit > 400 && getCredit <= 500) {
        score += 0
    }
}
```